# How to use Firebase emulators with Google cloud Pub/sub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-tools

I am working on using Firebase functions to listen to cloud pub/sub message. However, when I run on firebase local emulator, I can't get result from message

What I did:

- Set up firebase functions project in NodeJS
- Setup a pub/sub topic (name subscription-listener)
- In my NodeJS code, I wrote a sample code like below:

```
import { pubsub, logger } from "firebase-functions/v2";

export const helloWorld = pubsub.onMessagePublished(
  "subscription-listener",
  (event) => {
    console.log("Event: ", event.data);
    logger.log("Event: ", event.data);
  }
);
```

- Setup admin credential for emulated functions and start firebase emulator [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)
- Send a sample message with gcloud

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish subscription-listener --message '{"name":"Xenia"}' --project <MY_CLOUD_PROJECT_NAME>
```

What I expected was that the helloWorld function can listen to the message publish and log to my local terminal

I don't know which step I'm currently missing since I have no prior experience with this.

Comment: my assumption is that `gcloud` doesnt know about the emulator running locally, so the message is not send there but rather into GCP environment.

Comment: I tried to deploy with `firebase deploy` but it shows error like this `HTTP Error: 400, Could not create Cloud Run service helloworld. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 10`

Comment: that sounds like a very different problem, I would suggest to open it as another standalone question.